# The Open button does not work while downloading a file with more than 147 characters in IE 9

Tags: internet-explorer

When i click on an link to download the .MSG file , I get the 'open/save' dialoge box. But when I click on the 'open' button, it doesn't work.  I have to select save and one of the options from save.  I don't want to have to do that all the time.  Any way to get back to the open button working? I observed this happens only if the file name is more than 147 characters. For all the files (file name less than 146 char), the 'open' button works properly. Is this anything with the IE setting? Pl advise

Comment: Can you give a sample file name that does not work? I would help answer the question for other problems if there are any.

Comment: File name - RERequestforReviewApprovalofFPAApartmentOpportunityFundALPandFPAApartmentOpportunityFundLPcombinedastheGuarantorsforourLoansandSubjectofthisFAMforFundIII.msg

Comment: If I reduce the filename length from 153(excluding extension) to 142 as "RERequestforReviewApprovalofFPAApartmentOpportunityFundALPandFPAApartmentOpportunityFundLPcombinedastheGuar.msgantorsforourLoansandSubjectofth.msg" i dont have any issue with 'open' button. I can open successfully

Comment: I can reproduce it. Not just with MSG but with .js (JavaScript) file as well. Just checked it does not work on IE 11 but works on IE8.

Comment: Some how i managed to provide a fix/work around for this issue. I reduced the file length and added it to the

Comment: response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", strContentDisposition + strTrimmedFileName);. This name which is set to the header is been used just for display purpose and the actual file is read from a different location.